# What should be an ideal place for listening events pushed from server in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

hope you're all doing great, I was just curious to know what could be an ideal place for listening events pushed from server, I'm playing with socket-io and trying to make a chat application in which the server pushes messages to the client, here is the code

```
  getInitialState:function(){
 return {localstatemessages: ['hi'],remoteuserstatemessages:['hello']}},

render: function () {
this.ListenEvents();
    var localusermsgs=this.state.localstatemessages.map(function(Message){
        return(
            <SendMessage Message={Message}/>
        )
    });
    var recievedmsgs=this.state.remoteuserstatemessages.map(function(msg){
        return(
            <RecievedMessage Message={msg} />
        )
    })


    return (
        <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 pull-right">
            <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="page-header">
                        <div className="media">
                            <div className="media-left">
                                <img src={require("../_assets/_images/download.jpeg")} className="img-circle" alt="user image" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="media-body">
                                <h2 className="media-heading">peer user</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div className="media-right"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="chat_box">
                 <RecievedMessage Message={this.state.remoteusermsg}/>
                <SendMessage Message={this.state.usermsg}/> 

            </div>
            <div className="msg_area">
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <div className="input-group">
                            <textarea type="text" cols="5" rows="2" onKeyDown={this.sendMessage} className="form-control" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
                            <span className="input-group-btn">
                                <button className="btn btn-warning" type="button" onClick={this.sendMessage}>send</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
},
sendMessage: function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

        let target = event.target;
        var msg = target.value;
       // alert('message is: ' + msg);
        //event raising through ajax goes here
        socket.emit('chat mssg',msg);
       // alert('pushing msg ');
       var newlocalmsg= this.state.localstatemessages;
       newlocalmsg.push(msg);
         this.setState({localstatemessages:newlocalmsg});
        target.value='';


    }


},
handleRemoteMesssageUpdate:function(message){
    var remotemessages=this.state.remoteuserstatemessages;
    remotemessages.push(message);
    this.setState({remoteuserstatemessages:remotemessages})
},
ListenEvents:function(){
       socket.on('chat mssg',function (msg){
       // alert('pushing anothermsg');
      this.handleRemoteMesssageUpdate(msg);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

});

module.exports = ChatBox;here

the state remoteuserstatemessages updates three times for a single pushed events , i don't understand what is going on here, does the render function calls the ListenEvents repetitively ? how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `this.ListenEvents()` in `render()`, of course it will be called for many times.

Since you are using socket, you just need to intialize the connection once right? So better you call it in `componentWillMount()`

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.ListenEvents()
}
render(){
    // render code
}
```

More about React Component Lifecycle : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Thanks, it did a job.